# Display navigation when a viewController is displayed programatically

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm using https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu for my `Swift 4` application. It's working good, but I have problems to display a new `ViewController` programmatically and the `NavigationController`.

If I use:

```
let vc = MyViewController.self() //your view controller
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

All the `IBOutlet` are `nil` and the `ViewController` is not loaded.

And the same happens with:

```
let vc = MyViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

How I can display a new `ViewController` keeping the `Navigator` of the `SideMenu`?

Comment: Is your `MyViewController` contains storyboard view controller interface ? Like as using storyboard Id.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift/iOS: IBOutlet nil after loading view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453042/swift-ios-iboutlet-nil-after-loading-view-controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not creating the VC's view programmatically in code  , you have to load it either from storyboard

```
let yourVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourVC") as! YourVC
```

or nib

```
let yourVC = YourVC(nibName: "YourVCNibName", bundle: nil)
```